# SSO office add-in, Azure cli not install error, enven after azure cli is installed and "az --version" works

Tags: single-sign-on, office-addins, azure-cli, outlook-web-addins

Trying to setup office add-in with single sign on, but not able to get it working as it keeps prompting me to install Azure cli enven though i already have azure CLI
I tried reinstalling Azure cli via the prompt and also manually from microsoft installer but i still get the same error.

SSO office add-in
-> executing command "npm run configure-sso";

I get warning, Azure cli is not installed and the installations starts automatically.
after the installation is complete it says to run the command "npm run configure-sso" again, and i get the same warning "Azure cli is not installed" and the installations starts all over again.

`npm run configure-sso

> office-addin-taskpane-sso@0.0.0 configure-sso
> office-addin-sso configure manifest.xml

Azure CLI is not installed.  Installing now before proceeding - this could take a few minutes.`

I already have azure cli installed
and when i run the command "az --version" i get the expected output
`C:\Users\harshp>az --version
azure-cli                         2.53.0

core                              2.53.0
telemetry                          1.1.0

Dependencies:
msal                            1.24.0b2
azure-mgmt-resource             23.1.0b2

Python location 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\python.exe'
Extensions directory 'C:\Users\harshp.azure\cliextensions'

Python (Windows) 3.10.10 (tags/v3.10.10:aad5f6a, Feb  7 2023, 17:20:36) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]

Legal docs and information: aka.ms/AzureCliLegal

Your CLI is up-to-date.`

Comment: Did you try clearing out cache using `npm cache clean --force`? @tony

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and upon looking into what was really happening in the configurations checks it turns out that on my computer, Azure CLI is installed under the name "Microsoft Azure CLI (32-bit)" while the package that checks the installation is looking for "Microsoft Azure CLI" exactly.

If you override this in "node_modules/office-addin-sso/lib/configure.js:66" it should work :

```
cliInstalled = appsWindows.filter((app) => app.DisplayName === "Microsoft Azure CLI (32-bit)").length > 0;
```